# Adding a +/- Button to my calculator ? - Android

Tags: android, button, calculator

Okay So I want to add this +/- button to change the sign of the number currently being shown in the result window (An EditText Component)

Here's the OnClick Funciton at the button press of the button :

```
public void onClickListenerPM(View v) {
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if (press == '=') {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    double masag = -1 * Double.parseDouble(EditTextMsg);
    String s = Double.toString(masag);
    editText.setText(s);
}
```

What I've done is 
Taken the string from the EditText view ---> 
made it into a double  --->
Reverse , Put that into a string again , so that the sign of whatever number is reversed. --->
Show it in the edittext view.

But whenever I click the button, the app force Closes ...

What's going wrong ? I think the logic is correct but most probably the conversions are causing the function to malfunction. (Not sure though)

Can you spot anything that might be causing this ?

(This is defined in the activity class obviously...)

EDIT :
Answer :
    EditTextMsg = editText.getText().toString();

forgot to add this -.-

Answer (score 2):

You haven't posted how you extracted the `EditText` String value. Did you use ...

```
EditText edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_text_id);
String editTextMsg = edit.getText().toString();
```

... `toString` is important here! And I would rather use `Double.toString()` than `toString(double)`:

```
Double masag = -1 * Double.valueOf(editTextMsg);
String s = masag.toString();
```

here. Hope this helps ...

Cheers!

Comment: Ohh Shoot, turns out I wasn't updating the EditTextMsg string , So it couldn't find out *what* I was trying to convert...  Got it right now !